# Title bars on Chrome and Firefox changed after update 1/20/17

Tags: updates, firefox

Did anyone notice after the update today (Jan 20) that the title bars in Chrome and Firefox have changed? There is a clear division between the tab bar area and the top window border. This did not exist before. Even loading themes into the browsers does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This was part of a recent set of updates. The elementary GTK+ stylesheet was updated to make older (gtk2) applications look more like the new ones with the big header bars. Check their new [blog post](https://medium.com/elementaryos/loki-updates-for-the-new-year-ff6b6ba65531#6b83).